# Returning element within DocumentFragment fails, because node no longer exists

Tags: php, garbage-collection, creation

Here is a testcase that highlights an error I've run into.  I think the node is being destroyed/garbage collected/something after the function returns -- is there a better way I can go about this?

```
function render($doc) {

    $fragment = $doc -> createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment -> appendXML('<iframe foo="bar"/>');
    return $fragment -> childNodes -> item(0);
}

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$element = render($doc);

// Exception: Couldn't fetch DOMElement. Node no longer exists
echo $element -> tagName; // fails -- because element no longer exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating only one element there is no need to make a fragment. Just create the element and set its attribute.

```
function render($doc) {

    $element = $doc -> createElement('iframe');
    $element -> setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
    return element;
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$element = render($doc);

echo $element -> tagName;
```

Comment: This is just a test case, there could be any sort of things being added in fragment.  After the return of a "render", I want to test the element and see what's in there.

Comment: @ansiart why don't you return the fragment itself.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm doing now, it's just awfully strange that it's gcing an element that still exists -- since i'm not removing the node or anything.

Comment: @ansiart the fragment is garbage collected since there is no reference to it(even thought elements in it has) so naturally all its nodes will be destroyed.

Comment: yeah that doesn't make any sense, there IS a reference to it, it's child.  Oh well, doesn't matter, no biggie.  Thanks.

Comment: The true answer is really to never lose a reference to the parent fragment, if you ever overwrite the variable, it'll throw an exception as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround: simply call cloneNode() and return the clone:

`return $element->cloneNode();`

I agree that this is weird behavior...I don't understand why PHP does this, but at least there's a workaround that still allows you to use document fragments. For more complex fragments you may need to pass `true` to cloneNode to tell it to make a deep copy, I'm not sure.